# Can locals in NextJS load only once instead of loading for each page

Tags: next.js, internationalization, translation, i18next

This is my first time using NextJS, and I'm using i18next for internationalization, I used one common file for all my translations, When I browse the app I noticed this translation file is loaded on every page, I suppose this is happening because of `getStaticProps`

```
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common']))
    }
  };
}
```

I tried to set only one namespace and use it as the default NS but not worked

```
ns: ['common',], 
defaultNS: 'common',
```

Is there any way to load it only once instead of loading it for each page?